# Does null consume memory and disk space in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I am designing a database based on my project, but I am thinking of separating 2 collections which both has same 3 fields in a document but one of the collections has one more field with those 3 fields.

If I had to combine them into one collection, then I will be putting lots of null value to lots of documents. So I am thinking of separating those 2 categories so that memory consume can decrease.

If null value in a document doesn't take memory, I can merge them.

I heard null in mysql doesn't take any space or memory but not sure of mongo.

What is the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a `null` value takes up some space. Mostly for the name of the key (as the field is still present).

But

- it don't think it matters much
- you don't have to put a `null` value at all, you can just omit the key/field entirely (instead of `{_id: 123, name: "test", someData: null}` insert `{_id:123, name: "test" }`). That way it won't take up space.

Answer (score 1):

In  Mongodb  `null`  also  take some  space and  memory. 
it  is  a type  of  BSON type .

if  you  don't  have  the  field value   please  `$unset`  the  field

the  null  value don't affect the sortting  result, but  has some  differ  to  `find()`

`db.coll.find({age:null})`
The query returns both documents in the collection.

`db.coll.find({age:{$type:10}})`

this command  will return  the  documents who's  field value  is  `null` .